# push values to array in home.component from app.component

Tags: angular, typescript

i want to push informations into an array in a component out of app.component

i have an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b4bgzr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
but the push did not work.

is this possible to push informations in an array in e.g. home.component from app.component?

Comment: Hello, Manuel. From app component do you want to update data to home component ? right ?

Comment: Hi, yes in this example that is right. Maybe i have some cases where i need it the other way (update data in app component from e.g. home component)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working Demo in this [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tuyh1v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdata.service.ts)

Basically, You need to communicate between two components, and for this `service` is used for better communication between two components. Now, all related data array will be placed in service and you need to inject this service inside all related component.

**Data-Service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
   equipment: any[] = [
    {
      ID: 1,
      Name: 'Test-Equip1'
    },
    {
      ID: 2,
      Name: 'Test-Equip2'
    }
  ];
  constructor() {}
  updateEquipment(newRecord: any) {
    this.equipment = [...this.equipment, newRecord];
  }
}
```

Now, Inject this service first to home.component and you get value of data array inside home.component

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  equipment = this.dataService.equipment;
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}
}
```

Now, same inject service inside app.component too and push object to data service array, and that will reflect it to home component too.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   equip: string = '';
   equipment: any[] = [];
   
   constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

   ngOnInit() {
     this.equipment = this.dataService.equipment;
   }
   
   AddEquip() {
      this.dataService.updateEquipment({ ID: 3, Name: this.equip });
      this.equipment.push({ ID: 3, Name: this.equip });
      this.equip = '';
   }
}
```

This way you can update your data without injecting component.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the decorator @Input,your code would look like this:

1- home.component

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() equipment: any[] = [];
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

2- app.component

```
import { Component, VERSION, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  equip: string = '';
  equipment: any[] = [];
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
  AddEquip() {
    this.equipment.push({ ID: 3, Name: this.equip });
    this.equip = '';
  }
}
```

3- app.component html

```
<input type="text" (keydown.enter)="AddEquip()" [(ngModel)]="equip" /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
App-Component: {{ equipment | json }}
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<app-home [equipment]="equipment"></app-home>
```